# Looking for Word Lists for Passphrase Building

Tags: passwords

I have been looking for word lists of nouns, verbs, and adjectives that I could import and use into a passphrase building tool I'm working on.  Instead of grabbing every word in the English language, I have been trying to find simpler words that can be concatenated into sound passphrases.

Does anyone know of a resource like this?  I've tried the Googling and the Binging and the hippity and the hoppity but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wordlist that comes with (almost) all unix distributions. It can be found at `/usr/share/dict/words`.

[Here is the list, if you don't have a unix box](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords)

Comment: Not a simple list - how many people know the word Zoroastrian???  Sorry no bounty for this answer :-D

Comment: I do! Freddie Mercury was a Zoroastrian... ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Communicated easily over the phone" do you mean words that, when pronounced by a variety of speakers are generally hard to confuse with other words?  i.e.  Maybe "cape" sounds very unique but "fifteen" sounds too much like "fifty"?  If so, you have a hard task at hand.

You can get 'common' words by analyzing the Google Ngram set:  http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

You can determine 'sound uniqueness' using soundex/metaphone analysis.

If I were taking this on I would:

1. Get the most common 1-grams for a certain (recent) year.
2. Calculate/store the [double metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone#Double_Metaphone) for each word.
3. Group by the metaphone and see how many you get where the metaphone had only 1 common word associated with it.

So yeah, that isn't a simple list, but what you are asking for isn't simple either, sorry!

Comment: You're on the right track ers81239 but not quite, it's more about common words, i.e. every day words that any average English speaker could put in a sentence to give context if required.

Many word lists have the word "Zoroastrian" in them - unless you're a religious scholar this is meaningless and someone wouldn't even be able to put it in a sentence.

Fifteen and Fifty is fine since you could distinguish using one five and five Oh.

Hope this helps - and this is the closest answer to date, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you read the link to the Google Ngram database, it gives you a ranking, by year, of the most common words found in books that Google has scanned.  So while these words might be slightly more scholarly than conversational english, I think that conversational english is featured heavily.  Because they are in order, you are getting the 'most popular words.'  Not just a list of known words.

Comment: Cool, I was looking more for a pick up and run solution (even if it was paid), I've managed to download one of the files from the Ngram db (many were failing due to their large size - is there an ftp option???)  I can't actually open the file because it's 7GB in size, definitely could work given enough work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these:
http://ogden.basic-english.org/words.html
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_1000_basic_words
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Basic_English_alphabetical_wordlist

By using simple web scraping you can fetch a list of all those words and then make them unique.

Also in there are referenced some other links, check those too.

Comment: Close Paul (although not a simple grab/pay for a list), but not enough words between those for what I need.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Honestly I don't know where you'll find a list that big with simple words only, especially in an easy-to-grab form.

Comment: Yep may not Paul, although I'm surprised there's not a pay option out there for this.

Answer (score 0):

I totally recommend this:
http://packetstormsecurity.com/Crackers/wordlists/

Just kidding! Have you tried [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)? There are interfaces to it for various languages, platforms, etc. and it is extremely powerful.

Comment: Yep I've looked at WordNet from another answer on here, again NOT a simple list and would have to be edited manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at this but you may not like the answer.  The easiest way I can think is to find CSV lists on google by using the the search term 'nouns' or 'verbs' along with fyletype:csv.  Once you have found the files that met your criteria. I found quite a few on GITHub which you could do some github call or if not on GIT you could do a CURL or HTTP call to the file using the server-side language of your choice...Generated a comma separated list or an array (some kind of struct), then create a randomization function and shake up the list (grab one or two top words and splice in rand number using randrange or something similar).  You could then concat a string of words and numbers. Even easier if you could make a simple two or three field table of all your words (cut and paste them in) or import from the raw file... and do a query that does the same thing.  Select one or three random words and concat them and using the row numbers of the records to unique-ify them.

But two things are certain, you will need a consumptive process and you'll need string concatenation function.

Comment: Yep we already have a process to take 2 words and 1 number to make good strength phrase BUT our list of words is (like all the examples given) either too long (with horrible words) or too short.

Thanks everyone for answering though!